# How to clear custom property value in web part

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, custom-properties

I have created a custom property `ListName` in a Visual web part that takes string as input.

I am using a check condition in page load and if that check fails, I want to clear the text box (custom property) values.

I tried using the below code but didn't work.

```
ListName="" ;
```

Is is possible to clear the property value on server side?

Comment: It should work with that code, can you please try putting it in CreateChildControls instead?

Comment: @RobertLindgren This is odd. I had written a custom error using "WebPartPageUserException". I removed it and now the property is getting cleared on page load too. But thanks for the suggestion.